# Looping Save in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, database, spring-boot, frontend

I'm fairly new to full-stack development. I'm working on a project using angular, which has a form that submits data to a database once save is clicked. My question is, let's say I had an input box in the HTML file which allows the user to enter a quantity, and I wanted to submit the **same data** to the database that number of times, how could this be achieved?

From my previous programming experience, My first thought was to loop the save function 'x' times, but I'm unsure how I could extract the quantity from the input box of the HTML file, and how to run a for loop in the typescript file over save.

HTML file:

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [.
      formGroup]="editForm">


  // some data that gets submitted to the database when save is clicked (my goal is to get this data submitted 'x' number of times, rather then have the user continually save)


  <div class="block">
    <label for="quant">Choose a Quantity:</label>
    <input type="text" name="quantity"/>
  </div>

</form>
```

typescript file:

```
  save(): void {
    this.isSaving = true;
    const data = this.dataFormService.getData(this.editForm);
    if (data.id !== null) {
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.dataService.update(data));
    } else {
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.dataService.create(data));
    }
  }
```

Comment: its better you create two APIs one for inline edit save and another for bulk saving all the records, you can also set a flag called operationInd, which can have three values "U" for update "I" for insert and "D" for delete, this will prevent unnecessary saving of records that were not modified!

Comment: Alongside the formgroup, add a formcontrol, which you bind to the input. Then read the quantity from that formcontrol.